# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named packageA.innterPackageA

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, setuptools

I am working on a Python Package/App for an Api and i am getting some errors after installing it via pip install . and then trying to execute an example script using the package.

I am using the following structure:

```
README.md
setup.py
virtualenv
package
    /__init__.py
    /endpoints.py
    /model
        /__init__.py
        /modelA
        /modelB
        ....
    /params
        /__init__.py
        /paramA
        /paramB
        ...
```

I am using absolute imports in all modules:
e.g. package.model.modelA, ...

Setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='package',
    version='1.0',
    description='lorem ipsum',
    author='i am author',
    author_email='some mail',
    license='my name',
    packages=['package','package.model','package.params'],
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

(For this explanation I substituted the real names I did not use package as the package name,...)

Though after installing with pip and executing an example.py (lies outside the project) script it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package.model.modelA import ModelA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package.model'
```

Also I have no problem importing package.params.

What did I do wrong here, do I miss something?

Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: where is `example.py` in your file hierarchy?

Comment: Can you give us the location of your file pls ?

Comment: example.py is outside of the whole project it just imports the package which was installed before via pip install . in its directory

Comment: what file example.py? Just put it on Desktop for testing.

Comment: `modelA` is a package itself (at least it is a directory in the tree you provided), so it should be included explicitly, just like other packages. `packages = [..., 'package.model.modelA']`. If you don't want to assemble the list manually, use `setuptools.find_packages()` function.

Comment: Find out what exactly has been packaged. Look inside your distributions. For example `python3 -m tarfile -l dist/package-1.0.tar.gz` or `python3 -m zipfile -l dist/package-1.0-py3-none-any.whl`. Alternatively find the `SOURCES.txt` file in your `package.egg-info` directory and look at its content. Are all your modules correctly listed?